# How to do a Join in C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How can I do a Join in C # using the Entity Framework by default DataBase - First, as I am sitting doing this query in the database

```
public List <clsModel> list ()
{
    strQuery = "select mode.modModel, bra.braIdBrand from tblModel mode join tblBrand bra on bra.braIdBrand = mode.braIdBrand";
    List <clsModel> lstModel = db.Database.SqlQuery <clsModel> (strQuery) .ToList ();

    return lstModel;
}
```

but it always gives this error

> Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the
>   specified 'CadastroAtivo.Models.clsModelo'. A member of the type,
>    'modIdModelo', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader
>   with the same name.

I want to bring the templates together their respective tags, but only come the templates and the marks are blank (null) and I do not know why.

Class Model:

```
public class clsModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int modIdModel {get; set; }

        [Required (ErrorMessage = "Enter Template Name")]
        [StringLength (40, ErrorMessage = "BigName!")]
        [MinLength (3, ErrorMessage = "Enter a name with at least 3 digits")]
        [Display (Name = "Model")]
        public string modModel {get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Mark")]
        [Required (ErrorMessage = "Select brand")]
        public int braIdBrand {get; set; }
        [ForeignKey ("braIdBrand")]
        public clsBrand Brand {get; set; }

    }
```

Class Brand:

```
public class clsBrand
    {
        [Key]
        public int braIdBrand {get; set; }

        [Required (ErrorMessage = "Report a brand"]]
        [Display (Name = "Brand")]
        [StringLength (50, ErrorMessage = "BigName!")]
        [MinLength (3, ErrorMessage = "Tag name is short")]
        public string braBrand {get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection <clsModel> Model {get; set; }
    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have class mapped to table `tblBrand` ?

Comment: Yes, even if I only search the tags in the brand class, I can bring them all ... But if I do a search in the template class, it does not come with the tags.

Comment: according to the error message, Your type is incompatible with the query. If you can [edit] your question to include `clsdModel` it will help answering the question.

Comment: So I can not get the class to "see" by the foreign key

Comment: @ZoharPeled 
Ready

Comment: If your going to use the `[Key]` attribute you need to supply it in your query.

Comment: @mxmissile How would I do that? Sorry, I am learning

Comment: It totally depends on your table definitions and how your classes are mapped to said tables. If you using `EF`, your probably better off using `LINQ` for simple queries like this.

Comment: @mxmissile Could you put in the answer as it would with Linq?
And what would be my advantage using Linq in my repository. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making wild assumptions on your dbcontext, but you can try this:

```
var results = from model in db.clsModels
    join brand in db.clsBrands on model.brand equals brand into g
    select new { Model = model, Brands = g };
```

(cant test this at the moment wihtout my workstation or your dbcontext, but hopefully you get the idea)

The advantage to using `Linq`, is it is strongly typed. You can easily find errors during compilation.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
public List<clsModel> list()
{
    strQuery = "select mode.modModel, bra.braIdBrand from tblModel mode join tblBrand bra on bra.braIdBrand = mode.braIdBrand";
    IEnumerable<clsModel> result = db.ExecuteQuery<clsModel> (strQuery);
    return result.ToList();
}
```